# How can I use regex as a delimiter when importing a csv file with pandas with extra commas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-science

The csv file was sent to me/ I can not re delimit the columns

```
239845723,28374,2384234,AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV,Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee, 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).,2011-07-13 00:00:00,2011-07-13 00:00:00
```

I replaced the string letters to cover sensitive info, however the problem is apparent.

This is an example "problem row" in my csv. It should be sorted into 8 columns as follows:

```
col1: 239845723
col2: 28374
col3: 2384234
col4: AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV
col5: Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN
col6: Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee, 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).
col7: 2011-07-13 00:00:00
col8: 2011-07-13 00:00:00
```

As you can see, column 6 is where the problem occurs as there are commas in the string that cause pandas to delimit and create new columns incorrectly. How can I solve this problem? I was thinking regex would help, perhaps with the below setup. Any help is appreciated!

```
    csvfile = open(filetrace) 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    new_list=[]
    for line in reader:
        for i in line:
            #not sure
```

Comment: Just looking at the column in question, are there any consistent features to the data that you're looking to capture? For instance the example ends with a ., will they all end like that?

Comment: Hey JBuete! They do all end in periods, however, as in this example, there are also periods throughout the column 6 string

Comment: If you have a csv file with unescaped commas in the data, you don't really have a csv file. You have a bunch of lines with a bunch of commas in them.

Comment: you could read the file, use re to change the delimiting comma's to something unique, dump this into a StringIO, and read this with Pandas

Comment: @MaartenFabré Back to the same problem... how do you tell which commas are delimiting

Comment: @AdiSrinivasan exactly. That was my question to you. If you cannot discern, you will have to tackle the problem at the source, and use a different delimiter when exporting the data

Comment: @MaartenFabré check out the answer I marked, regex worked really well in this case. Common data science problem when you are sent a csv usually from non-programmer types who dont realize the importance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, without knowing the specifics of the file or the data I can offer a regex solution that *could* work if the data is consistent (and has the period at the end of column 6). We can do it without using the csv module and just the regex module.

```
import re

# make the regex pattern here
pattern = r"([\d\.]*),([\d\.]*),([\d\.]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*\.?),([\d\-\s:]*),([\d\-\s:]*)"

# open the file with 'with' so you don't have to worry about closing it
with open(filetrace) as f:
    for line in f:  # iterate through the lines
        values = re.findall(pattern, line)[0]  # re.findall returns a list 
                                               # literal of a tuple
        # record the values somewhere
```

`values` here is an 8-tuple containing the values from each of the columns that you had in your original csv, just use/store them however you want.

Best of luck with it!

Comment: Wow this was amazing JBuete! Worked like a charm after a few minor tweaks will definitely save this for later use

Answer (score 3):

Istead of going to regex, read the csv with delimiter ',', You can extract the last two dates and store it in a list. Then fill the dates with `''` then join the columns you want and the delete the rest. Example

If you have a csv file :

```
239845723,28374,2384234,AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV,Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee, 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).,2011-07-13 00:00:00,2011-07-13 00:00:00
239845723,28374,2384234,AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV,Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee 2 for WVEee VEWE.).,2011-07-13 00:00:00,2011-07-13 00:00:00
239845723,28374,2384234,AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV,Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).,2011-07-13 00:00:00,2011-07-13 00:00:00
```

Then

```
df = pd.read_csv('good.txt',delimiter=',',header=None)
# Get the Dates from all the DataFrame 
dates = [[item] for i in df.values for item in i if '2011-' in str(item)]
# Merge two Dates for each column
dates = pd.DataFrame([x+y for x,y in zip(dates[0::2], dates[1::2])])
# Remove the dates present 
df = df.replace({'2011-': np.nan}, regex=True).replace(np.nan,'')

#Get the columns you want to merge 
cols = df.columns[4:]
# Merge the columns 
df[4] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1)
df[4] = df[4].replace('\,+$', '',regex=True)
#Drop the Columns 
df = df.drop(df.columns[5:],axis=1)
#Concat the dates 
df = pd.concat([df,dates],axis=1)
```

Output : print(df)

```
           0      1        2                      3  \
0  239845723  28374  2384234  AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV   
1  239845723  28374  2384234  AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV   
2  239845723  28374  2384234  AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV   

                                                   4                    0  \
0  Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera ...  2011-07-13 00:00:00   
1  Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera ...  2011-07-13 00:00:00   
2  Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse...  2011-07-13 00:00:00   

                     1  
0  2011-07-13 00:00:00  
1  2011-07-13 00:00:00  
2  2011-07-13 00:00:00
```

Ouput of the 4th column :

```
['Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee, 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).',

 'Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN,Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd bdfwd dsf (sdv seves 4-6), sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee 2 for WVEee VEWE.).',

'Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN sebsbe sve(sevsev esvse 7-10) fsesef fesevsesv PaVvin (1 evesve vEV VEWee 2 for WVEee VEWE. paper tuff as sWEFEWoon as VEWeew.).']
```

If you want to change column index

```
df.columns = [i for i in range(df.shape[1])]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This requires that there are always the same number of commas in column 6. Op didn't specify but I suspect the number of commas are variable. If I'm correct then this solution will not work.

Comment: Yes, this works in the case of this one row. Yet I need to generalize for a couple million rows with different input strings, this was one example problematic row

Answer (score 1):

Since you know exactly how many columns you need and there is only one problematic column, we can split the first few off from the left and rest from the right.  In other words, you don't need `regex`

Read file into single string

```
csvfile = open(filetrace).read()
```

Make `pd.Series`

```
s = pd.Series(csvfile.split('\n'))
```

Split `s` and limit it to 5 splits, which should be 6 columns

```
df = s.str.split(',', 5, expand=True)
```

Now split the right side limited to 2 splits

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-1].join(df.iloc[-1].str.rsplit(',', 2, expand=True))
```

---

Another way starting from `s`

```
left = s.str.split(',', 5)
right = left.str[-1].str.rsplit(',', 2)

df = pd.DataFrame(left.str[:-1].add(right).tolist())
```

---

I ran this and took the transpose to make it easier to read on screen

```
df.T



                                                   0
0                                          239845723
1                                              28374
2                                            2384234
3                              AEVNE EFU 5 GN OR WNV
4                             Owinv Vnwo Badvw 5 VIN
5  Ginq 2 jnwve wef evera wve 6 vwe as fgsb bfd b...
6                                2011-07-13 00:00:00
7                                2011-07-13 00:00:00
```

Comment: Maybe I didnt state it clearly but this is one example problem row, many like this exist and I need to correct all of them in my file

Comment: @AdiSrinivasan are you trying to split the entire file into an 8 column dataframe?